# to find if any overlapping rectangles exist in n number of rectangles

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, intervals, pseudocode

Assume that each rectangle is rectilinearly oriented (sides parallel to the
x- and y-axes), so that we represent a rectangle by its minimum and maximum xand y-coordinates. Give an O.n lg n/-time algorithm to decide whether or not a set
of n rectangles so represented contains two rectangles that overlap. Your algorithm
need not report all intersecting pairs, but it must report that an overlap exists if one
rectangle entirely covers another, even if the boundary lines do not intersect.

my solution:
  Let R be an array containing rectangles represented as (x_int, y_int) where x_int represents interval [x1, x2] and y_int represents interval [y1, y2] if the 4 cornesrs of rectacle are (x1, y1), (x1, y2), (x2, y1) and (x2, y2).Let the indexing start from 1. this solution is based on the fact that two rectangles overlap if and only if their  x_int overlap and y_int overlap.

```
FindOverlap(R, n):
  T = IntervalTree()   // T is a interval tree capable of checking if a given
                       // interval is overlapping with any interval in the tree
                       // and inserting interval in the tree in log(n) time.
  for i in [1,n]:
      x_int, y_int = R[i][1], R[i][2]

      interval_Index = T.IntervalSearch(x_int)  // Returns 0 if there is no interval 
                                           // in T which overlaps x_int , else 
                                           // returns index of the interval which
                                           // overlaps x_int 
      if interval_Index != 0:

          if R[interval_Index][2] overlaps y_int:

              return i, interval_Index

      T.InsertInterval(x_int, i)          // inserts interval x_int into T with 
                                          //associated index i
  return False
```

Is there anything wrong in this ? Will this algorithm work correctly?

Comment: In `if R[interval_Index][1] overlaps y_int:`, you probably want `R[interval_Index][2]` instead.

Comment: @Nelfeal yes, I mistakenly typed 1. Is there no other mistake?

Comment: This doesn't work, because there can be more than one rectangle with an x-interval that overlaps the new x-interval, and you're only looking at one.  If you check them all, then it won't be O(N log N) anymore.

Comment: @MattTimmermans any better would be much appriciated. I agree with what you said. What will be the time complexity if I check  all y_int whose corresponding x_int overlaps with the new x_int? How can I modify the algorithm to reduce time complexity to O(n log n)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a scan line algorithm that meets the requirements:

You'll need a binary search tree (BST) that keeps rectangles ordered by min X coordinate, and a priority queue that keeps rectangles ordered by max Y coordinate.

1. Sort the rectangles by min Y coordinate: O(N log N)
2. Iterate through the rectangles in min Y order.  For each one:

   1. Remove all rectangles with max Y coordinates less than the new rect min Y from both the priority queue and the BST:  O(N log N) all together
   2. Insert the new rectangle into the BST.  If you detect that its X interval overlaps with the rectangles to its left or right in the BST, then you've found an overlap and you're done.  This step also takes O(N log N) all together.
   3. Insert the new rectangle into the priority so that you know when to remove it in step 2.1.  Again O(N log N)

Comment: A BST doesn't work. Picture N rectangles of the same size and with the same Y position and increasing X position, so all arranged in a horizontal line from left to right. No rectangle is ever removed from the queue and for each rectangle, you need to check all previous ones in the BST for an overlap, making the whole thing O(N^2). However, if you replace the BST with an interval tree, I believe this can work (and it becomes similar to using a 2D interval tree).

Comment: Why would you check all the previous ones?  If a new rectangle overlaps any others, then it will overlap the one on its left or its right, so you only need to check those as you do the insert.  That's why the BST is ordered by X coordinate

Comment: Oh right I was mistakenly thinking of checking more than the two rectangles directly next to the new one in the BST. My mistake.

Comment: @MattTimmermans In step 2.1 did you mean to check the overlap between new rectangle's X interval and successor or predecessor of newly inserted rectangle(those are the rectangles in BST which are in left and right of newly inserted rectangle ordered by min X coordinate). Because left and right childern of this rectangle in BST may be nil and still predecessor and successor may exist . Please clarify this

Comment: @MattTimmermans, and you also mentioned that if a new rectangle overlaps any others,then it will overlap on its left or right. take the case of rectangles having X intervals: [1,5], [2,3], [4,6], [7,8]. they are ordered by min X. The third rectangle's X interval intersects with first, not with any of second or fourth.

Comment: Re 2.1: No overlap checking is done in 2.1.  Overlaps are checked when rectangles are inserted into the BST in 2.2.  You check predecessor and successor, not left and right children.  Re example:  When you inserted [2,3], you would have noticed that it overlaps [1,5].  The BST always contains non-overlapping rectangles.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Matt Timmermans's comment: this does not work because you could have a situation where three rectangles overlap in X, and only the last two overlap in Y. In this case, you only check for overlap in Y between the third and the first, not between the third and the second.

Moreover, if you try checking all rectangles that overlap the current one in X for overlap in Y, you end up in O(N^2) complexity in the worst case: imagine all N rectangles overlap in X but only the last two overlap in Y.

What you need is a two-dimensional interval tree, that is an interval tree in X where each node also contains an interval tree in Y for the subtree. Insertion and query are still O(log N), which makes the whole algorithm O(N log N).

Comment: Thanks . Thats what I was thinking after Matt's comment. One dimensional interval tree ain't enough to solve this 2 dimensional problem in linearthmic time.

Comment: to implement a 2 dimensional interval tree , if I  modify the ```IntervalSearch()``` function such that it include  the checking of  y_int overlap along with x_int with an AND operator, keeping everything else as it is, will it work?

Comment: What do you mean by "with an AND operator"? If you mean maintaining two interval trees, one for X and one for Y, and checking both, then it will not be in O(N log N). A true 2D interval tree has a separate subtree in Y for each subtree in X.